# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - in Leaflet .eachLayer function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm totally new to leaflet and very new to javascript, and I'm having a hard time figuring out where this error is coming from.

I'm trying to determine which features from a geoJSON object are visible in the current map extent and then list those in a  tag. The error I am getting says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in leaflet.js.

The following is relevant parts of my code. The geoJSON is loading and displayed the way I want and everything, I am just not getting anything to display in my HTML.

```
geojson.eachLayer(function (lyr){
        f = lyr.feature;
        if (map.getBounds().contains(f.latLng)){
            console.log(lyr)
            var extentresults = [
            '<li>', f.properties.Author + ", " + f.properties.Title + ", " , '</li>'
            ].join("\n");
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += extentresults;
        }
    });
```

geojson is my geoJSON object and map is my map object.
In my HTML I just have:

```
<div>
<ul id="list"></ul>
</div
```

Here is a screenshot of the error in my console

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the console..Will you please add it to your question?